# BASH Script to run a command only if a host is alive

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to create a BASH script to run a command after verifying a host is alive. I was thinking of using the `fping` command, but I can't figure out how to create a conditional loop to proceed with running the command I need to run **only** if the host I am `fping`ing is up. If I run the command before the host is available, I need to restart the whole machine...

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```bsh
if fping -q $MYHOST; then
  do my command
fi
```

Alternatively, this may make sense

```bsh
if ! fping -q $MYHOST; then
  # exit on error
  echo "host $MYHOST is not alive"
  exit 1
fi
do more commands
bla bla bla
```